# Evaluation order of increment operations in c

Tags: c, operator-precedence, post-increment

I executed following following code.

```
int main(void)
{
    int c;
    c=0;
    printf("%d..%d..%d \n", c,c,c);
    c=0;
    printf("%d..%d..%d \n", c,c,c++);
    c=0;
    printf("%d..%d..%d \n", c,c++,c);
    c=0;
    printf("%d..%d..%d \n", c++,c,c);
```

return 0;}

I expected the output as

> 0..0..0
>
> 1..1..0
>
> 0..1..0
>
> 0..0..0

But the output(compiled with gcc) was

> 0..0..0
>
> 1..1..0
>
> 1..0..1
>
> 0..1..1

What is wrong with my expectation?
In gcc ,evaluation order is from right to left. Is It?

Comment: What happens if you make all incremented, all 3 of them? Does it print 3,2,1 ?

Comment: I would mark this as a duplicate except the duplicates I found were older than the C 2011 standard, and we ought to have an updated answer for the new standard. Is there another question covering this topic that addresses the C 2011 standard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is wrong with my expectation?

Evaluation order of function parameters is not specified - it is left up to the implementation. Moreover, there is no [*sequence point*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) <sup>*</sup> between the parameters, so using a modified parameter again before a sequence point cannot give you a predictable result: it is undefined behavior ([thanks, Eric, for providing a reference to the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907520/evaluation-order-of-increment-operations-in-c/17907551?noredirect=1#comment26159204_17907551)).

If you want a particular evaluation order, you need to evaluate your parameters as full expressions (that forces a sequence point between each of them):

```
int arg1 = c++;
int arg2 = c;
int arg3 = c;
// This: printf("%d..%d..%d \n", c++,c,c);
// Becomes this:
printf("%d..%d..%d \n", arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Sequence point is a fancy name for a place in code after which you can count on side effects, such as increments or decrements, of all preceding expressions to have been applied.

Comment: how to specify evaluation order of function?

Comment: @Shihab You can force evaluation order by evaluating each parameter separately.

Comment: This is not merely a matter of unspecified evaluation order. The entire behavior is undefined by the C standard, not just the order in which the parameters are evaluated. Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.5 2: “If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for providing a reference!